# PDF to Tiff Error: sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Didn't expect more than one scan

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio, icepdf

Please suggest how to solve below error,while converting pdf to tiff.The pdf has multiple pages with scanned (Example Application form scanned and converted to PDF).Issue with if a pdf page has two or more scanned images in a single pdf page then below error is coming.
 **sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Didn't expect more than one scan**.

```
sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Didn't expect more than one scan
    at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.readImage(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.produceImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:119)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:246)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
```

**We are using icepdf-viewer.jar,jai_core.jar,jai_imageio.jar and icepdf-core.jar**below is the code snipped

```
public void capturePageTiff(int pageIndex) throws IOException {
    boolean hasPageSizeChanged = hasPageSizeChanged(pageIndex);
    // cache the existing buffer as they are costly to recreate.
    if (hasPageSizeChanged(pageIndex) || bufferedImage == null) {
        if (hasPageSizeChanged) {
            currentPageSize = calculatePageSize(pageIndex, "NEW");
        }
        bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(
                (int) currentPageSize.getWidth(),
                (int) currentPageSize.getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY,
                cm);
        imageGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        img = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
    }
    // finally paint the content.
    Catalog catalog = document.getCatalog();
    //System.out.println("iiii " + pageIndex);
    Page page = catalog.getPageTree().getPage(pageIndex, this);
    // System.out.println(page);
    AffineTransform prePaintTransform = imageGraphics.getTransform();
    page.paint(imageGraphics, GraphicsRenderingHints.PRINT,
            Page.BOUNDARY_CROPBOX,
            rotation, scale, null,
            true, false);//Error is coming here
    catalog.getPageTree().releasePage(page, this);
    imageGraphics.setTransform(prePaintTransform);
    // write the captured page to the tiff.
    if (pageIndex == 0) {
        writer.write(null, img, param);
    } else {           
        try {
            writer.writeInsert(-1, img, param);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);
            writer.writeToSequence(img, param);
            writer.endWriteSequence();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Dear Lothar, The above is the full stack

Comment: The exception is coming on     page.paint(imageGraphics, GraphicsRenderingHints.PRINT,
            Page.BOUNDARY_CROPBOX,
            rotation, scale, null,
            true, false);//Error is coming here

Comment: How do you know that the exception is thrown in that line if the stacktrace above is the complete one? No mention of any class outside of the package of sun.awt.image is in it.

Comment: Lothar, the conversion from pdf to tiff is converting from 1st page to last page. The stack trace is given above is when debug the program it showed on that line while converting at page number 15th page.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your pages having more than one scanned image, it's a about the embedded images in JPEG format containing multiple scans (ie. a progressive JPEG), where a baseline JPEG was expected.

Comment: Thanks Haraldk, How can we solve this issue any solution.

Comment: That depends... Can you change the way the PDFs are generated? If so, make them contain only non-progressive JPEGs. If not, have a look at the ICEpdf documentation, and see if you can change the JPEG decoder it is using (to ImageIO for instance). It may also be interesting to see if the embedded JPEG is decodable by other libraries, otherwise there's no point in changing. If there's no API for changing decoder, you still can hack it, it's open source. Finally, you could try a different PDF library to render your pages altogether. Options appear in order of estimated work (easy to hard). ;-)

Comment: PS: You should probably talk to ICEpdf support before trying to implement different JPEG decoding (especially if you have ICEpdf pro), they might have a solution for you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the file in question on the ICEpdf support forums.  I'm surprised to see the sun stack trace as it would seem to indicate you are using a very old version of ICEpdf.  We moved away from the JPEGImageDecoder some time ago in favour of ImageIO.  What version of ICEpdf are you using?

Comment: Thanks pcorless, issue raised in forum and the version i am using here is 4.2.2_3